# Preparing for an exam on handing Exceptions, Why do we need throws?

Tags: java, computer-science

So I'm just starting to learn about Exception handling and I'm by something in the output of this code, So I wanted to check if I was going to get an arithmetic Exception if I did not "throws" the right class for the exception that will occur in the method num, in this case division by 0 .

```
public static void num(int k)//throws Exception
 {
         int ll = k /0;
}



public static void main(String [] args)  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in) ;

    try {
        num(2) ;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Handled");

    }
```

The exception is still being caught by catch in the main even though I did not use "Throws " in the method num.
I'm so confused to why this is happening, What would be the point of throws if I can still handle the exception regardless

Comment: I should add that Im getting "Handled " in the output

Comment: Because the java runtime "throws" an exception for you when you divide by `0`. Specifically, it throws "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"